# Paypal integration to apps

Tags: android, ios, ios6, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am finding apps that has integrated paypal trasaction. I have lot of doubts related to paypal integration. I tried to solve them by asking questions on SO but my doubt's list keep growing. I finally want to check some app that has paypal integration and perform real transaction. I simply want to transfer money from userA to userB's paypal account.

I have searched for such apps but has not found any.

Please suggest me such apps. It can be any of iOS and android.

**Note :** I have heard that using paypal in app, only app owner can receive money and not any other person. Is it true? This is the most crucial doubt I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it it 100% true that using paypal SDK only the owner of app can send or receive money. It is something like this that user creates an app on paypal, gets different keys and codes from there only and then integrate them in the SDK provided by paypal.

now you can use this APP for making payment of "Actual physical goods." If they are intangible then u must have to use iOS In app payments

Comment: I need to allow 2 users to pay to each other. Do I must use in-app? I mean in-app won't be useful in this case. Any suggestion? Once again, if you know any app that use paypal then notify me.

Comment: "ebay" it uses paypal. other than this you cannot send payment from person A to person B

Comment: Sorry I could not understand. Other than this means? Which one allows to transfer money from userA to userB? Is there any official document stating the fact that only app owner can receive money?

Comment: Does MPL allow transferring money from userA to userB?

Comment: Hey @Geek ... have you implemented the transfer of money in application . Can you tell me how, I need to do the exact same thing as yours.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I postponed the idea of implementing it. So, sorry for now. :) I will post an answer whenever I implement it.